# Stormpath Spring Boot

Tags: html, web-applications, spring-boot, stormpath

I cloned the [official Stormpath Spring Boot tutorial git repo](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-boot-tutorial), generated and saved my key pair at `~/.stormpath/apiKey.properties`, built the project (`mvn clean package`), and ran it (`java -jar target/*.jar`).

The tutorial web app demonstrates a webpage with three tabs (Home, Dashboard, Login) that show after the user log-in.

It works as expected on one machine.  When I repeat the same process on any other machine the Dashboard tab does not show.  All machines use openjdk-1.7.

[image: Stormpath Spring Boot tutorial]

Comment: Are you hosting it on both machines, or hosting it on one and accessing the page from both?

Comment: It works when I access the web app from the same machine I'm hosting it on.  Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: By design, Stormpath requires https connections for anything other than localhost. It is likely that this is the root cause of the failure on this machine. On newer versions of the SDK, there is a lengthy log message that speaks to this. I will update this example to use the latest version of the Stormpath Java SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the project you referenced to the latest version of the Java SDK and I pushed it up.

In any case other than connections from localhost, you should see this message:

```
2016-05-18 21:54:50.811  WARN 94320 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.f.a.CookieAuthenticationResultSaver : INSECURE IDENTITY COOKIE CONFIGURATION: Your current Stormpath SDK account cookie configuration allows insecure identity cookies (transmission over non-HTTPS connections)!  This should typically never occur otherwise your users will be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.  For more information in Servlet-only environments, please see the Security Notice here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html#https-required and the documentation on authentication state here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html#authentication-state and here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html#cookie-config (the callout entitled 'Secure Cookies').  If you are using Spring Boot, Spring Boot-specific documentation for these concepts are here: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/login.html#security-notice https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/login.html#authentication-state and https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/login.html#cookie-storage
```

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is a nice service to setup an SSL tunnel to a service running on localhost. There are others too.

Feel free to send us an email at: support@stormpath.com if this doesn't resolve the issue for you.